# Personalize Matplotlib toolbar with log feature

Tags: python, matplotlib, toolbar

I have a simple plot with a toolbar. I added a widget but can't manage to find the way to tell this button to switch the main plot from normal view to log view. I don't know how to access the data given to the plot from this button event (pickerToggled(self,checked)).

Here is the code I have so far.

```
import sys, os, math
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class NavigationToolbar( NavigationToolbar2QTAgg ):

    picked=pyqtSignal(int,name='picked')

    def __init__(self, canvas, parent ):
        NavigationToolbar2QTAgg.__init__(self,canvas,parent)
        self.clearButtons=[]
        # Search through existing buttons
        # next use for placement of custom button
        next=None
        for c in self.findChildren(QToolButton):
            if next is None:
                next=c
            # Don't want to see subplots and customize
            if str(c.text()) in ('Subplots','Customize'):
                c.defaultAction().setVisible(False)
                continue
            # Need to keep track of pan and zoom buttons
            # Also grab toggled event to clear checked status of picker button
            if str(c.text()) in ('Pan','Zoom'):
                c.toggled.connect(self.clearPicker)
                self.clearButtons.append(c)
                next=None

        # create custom button
        pm=QPixmap(32,32)
        pm.fill(QApplication.palette().color(QPalette.Normal,QPalette.Button))
        painter=QPainter(pm)
        painter.fillRect(6,6,20,20,Qt.red)
        painter.fillRect(15,3,3,26,Qt.blue)
        painter.fillRect(3,15,26,3,Qt.blue)
        painter.end()
        icon=QIcon(pm)
        picker=QAction("Pick",self)
        picker.setIcon(icon)
        picker.setCheckable(True)
        picker.setToolTip("Pick data point")
        self.picker = picker
        button=QToolButton(self)
        button.setDefaultAction(self.picker)

        # Add it to the toolbar, and connect up event
        self.insertWidget(next.defaultAction(),button)
        picker.toggled.connect(self.pickerToggled)

        # Grab the picked event from the canvas
        canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',self.canvasPicked)

    def clearPicker( self, checked ):
        if checked:
            self.picker.setChecked(False)

    def pickerToggled( self, checked ):
        if checked:
            #### code to add to display plot in logscale


            for c in self.clearButtons:
                c.defaultAction().setChecked(False)
            self.set_message('Reject/use observation')

        else: # linear plot
           #### code to come back to linear scale plot

    def canvasPicked( self, event ):
        if self.picker.isChecked():
            self.picked.emit(event.ind)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.x=[i*0.1 for i in range(30)]
        self.y=[math.sin(x) for x in self.x]
        self.picked=[]
        self.setWindowTitle('Custom toolbar')

        self.frame = QWidget()

        self.fig = Figure((4.0, 4.0))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setParent(self.frame)

        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        # Create the navigation toolbar, tied to the canvas
        # and link the clicked event
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.frame)
        self.toolbar.picked.connect(self.addPoint)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)
        vbox.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.frame.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        while self.axes.lines:
            self.axes.lines[0].remove()
        self.axes.plot(self.x,self.y,'b+',picker=5)
        xp=[self.x[i] for i in self.picked] 
        yp=[self.y[i] for i in self.picked] 
        self.axes.plot(xp,yp,'rs')
#        self.axes.set_xscale('log')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def addPoint(self,index):
        if index in self.picked:
            self.picked.remove(index)
        else:
            self.picked.append(index)
        self.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Judging from the design of your `pickerToggled`, it looks to me like you're trying to select your data in linear units but display them in log, is that right?  I would probably separate the linear/log functionality from the picker, rather than use a toggle. So I'd make a new custom button from which you can send signals back to the MainWindow (where you can access the data and plot accordingly), just like you do with your picker.

Comment: I think you are right Ajean. That's exactly what I should (and want to do). My only problem, and it's probably a rookie problem, is how can I send this signal back to the MainWindow (class that contains my data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something of a choice in design, but here's a synopsis of what I would probably do, which may not necessarily be the best but will work.  You already have a draw function which re-makes your plot according to certain parameters, so for linear/log I would add a property to your `MainWindow` that represents a log toggle.

### In MainWindow

```
# In the __init__ before the call to self.draw
self.islog = False

# Connect the new signal (defined below)
self.toolbar.picked.connect(self.addPoint)
self.toolbar.logtog.connect(self.logtoggle) # new
```

Then in `self.draw` I would place the plotting code into an if statement handling linear or log.

```
# In place of your commented line
if self.islog:
    self.axes.set_xscale('log')
else:
    self.axes.set_xscale('linear')
```

And construct the new method for toggling the setting:

```
def logtoggle(self, checked):
    self.islog = checked
    self.draw()
```

### In NavigationToolbar

As for getting a signal back from the toolbar, you are already sending a custom signal so you have the formula for it.  Something like:

```
picked=pyqtSignal(int,name='picked')
logtog = pyqtSignal(bool) # new signal
```

Then add a custom button just like you did the other, make it checkable like the other...

```
# New button stuff
pm=QPixmap(32,32)
pm.fill(QColor(0,0,255)) # Uniform fill just for demonstration
ic = QIcon(pm)
ac = self.addAction(ic, "Toggle Log") # This will end up on the far right - you can place it wherever you want
ac.setCheckable(True)
ac.toggled.connect(self.logtoggle)
```

Then of course write the toolbar method to emit the signal:

```
def logtoggle(self, checked):
    self.logtog.emit(checked)
```

I added all the above to the code you provided and it works just fine.  You had all the ingredients there already, I just added some similar things.

Comment: Sounds wonderful. I'm gonna try that. Thanks a lot Ajean for spending the time solving my issue.

Comment: This is brilliant. It works. And in the same time it helped me learn a few concepts I didn't get before… Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad I could help!  As a brand new SO user you can't vote yet, but you *can* accept the answer to indicate it worked for you. Thanks!